# runtime error 13 type mismatch vba

Tags: vba, ms-access

I get this error message but can't seem to get around it. please help.
thanks

```
For i = 2 To lRow
         If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Rep" Then
          Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & Cells((Left(4, Cells(i, 1).Value)) & Cells(i, 2).Value).Value & "Here"
```

Comment: For i = 2 To lRow
         If Cells(i, 6).Value = "Rep" Then
          Cells(i, 7).Value = Cells(i, 3).Value & Cells((Left(4, Cells(i, 1).Value)) & Cells(i, 2).Value).Value & "Here"

Comment: You're trying to concatenate an array and the string "Here".  What is the code *supposed* to do?

Comment: it is to concatenate the value from different cells, add "Here" at the end. put the value in cell (i, 6)

Comment: What is `Cells((Left(4, Cells(i, 1).Value)) & Cells(i, 2).Value).Value` ? what are you trying to get here ? I know `Left(4, Cells(i, 1).Value)`

Comment: trying to take the value in cells (i,3), (i,1) and (i, 2) to add in cell (i, 7)

Comment: `Left(4, Cells(i, 1).Value)` looks like it has its parameters switched, i.e. should be `Left(Cells(i, 1).Value, 4)` - but that by itself won't fix your code

Comment: I made the change but now it giving an "Invalid procedure call or argument error" at the same line

Comment: If the change that didn't work is the one provided in Wayne's answer, check what values exist in columns A, B and C of the row that is causing the error.  You may have `#N/A!` values or something else that can't be concatenated together.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment "...trying to take the value in cells (i,3), (i,1) and (i, 2)..." the following will do what you want.  What is throwing people off is where you are using 'Left(...'. Are you trying to take **part** of some cell? If so, please clarify what you need (i.e. "all of cell i,3; Left n characters of cell 1, 1, all of cell i, 2, plus append 'Here' to that string)

```
Cells(i, 7).value = Cells(i, 3).value & Left(Cells(i, 1).value, 4) & Cells(i, 2).value & "Here"
```

Comment: sorry for the confusion. correct. I am trying to take the 4 left characters in cell (i, 1)

Comment: Then see the updated answer. You would need '...& Left(Cells(i, 1).value, 4) &...'

Comment: I made the change but now it giving an "Invalid procedure call or argument error" at the same line

Comment: Like @YowE3K asked... bad values? Or not?